# how to use diferent properties files in JDI

Tags: jdi, jdiframework

Is it possible to use different settings files in JDI? For example `test.properties` & `stage.properties` and start by passing as a parameter, for example: `gradle -Dtarget=stage ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in JDI 1.1.. please use JdiSettings.jdiSettingsPath = "prod.properties"
for this purposes